# Sql Server: Compare multiple dates, remove duplicates and add new column all in one

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

What would be the best solution for the following problem?

So I have a stored procedure that inserts into a temporary table information like so:

```
    Id | Name |   Date            |  Age  | Bin |Status| Description |  Warn1
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    01 | abcd |2016-01-01 15:00:00|  17   | 0   | 40   | Done        |  0
    01 | abcd |2016-01-01 11:00:00|  17   | 0   | 30   | Waiting     |  0
    01 | abcd |2016-01-01 10:00:00|  17   | 0   | 10   | Started     |  0

    02 | zxcv |2016-01-02 11:30:00|  18   | 0   | 35   | Error       |  0
    02 | zxcv |2016-01-02 11:00:00|  18   | 0   | 30   | Waiting     |  0
    02 | zxcv |2016-01-02 10:00:00|  18   | 0   | 10   | Started     |  0

    03 | yttr |2016-01-02 12:30:00|  16   | 0   | 30   | Waiting     |  0
    03 | yttr |2016-01-02 10:00:00|  16   | 0   | 10   | No desc     |  0

    04 | huuo |2016-01-02 11:30:00|  17   | 0   | 40   | Done        |  0
    04 | huuo |2016-01-02 09:00:00|  17   | 0   | 30   | Waiting     |  0
    04 | huuo |2016-01-02 08:00:00|  17   | 0   | 10   | Started     |  0

    05 | test |2016-01-03 10:00:00|  10   | 0   | 11   | Error       |  0
    05 | test |2016-01-03 09:00:00|  10   | 0   | 10   | Started     |  0
```

I have 2 variables @maxStatus and @description, I would like to keep all information where any of the same id's have Status = @maxStatus and Description = @description.

For example if @maxStatus = 40 and @description='Done' the resulting table should be:

```
Id | Name |   Date            |  Age  | Bin |Status| Description |  Warn1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
01 | abcd |2016-01-01 15:00:00|  17   | 0   | 40   | Done        |  0
01 | abcd |2016-01-01 11:00:00|  17   | 0   | 30   | Waiting     |  0
01 | abcd |2016-01-01 10:00:00|  17   | 0   | 10   | Started     |  0
04 | huuo |2016-01-02 11:30:00|  17   | 0   | 40   | Done        |  0
04 | huuo |2016-01-02 09:00:00|  17   | 0   | 30   | Waiting     |  0
04 | huuo |2016-01-02 08:00:00|  17   | 0   | 10   | Started     |  0
```

if @maxStatus = 11 and @description='Error' the resulting table should be:

```
 Id | Name |   Date            |  Age  | Bin |Status| Description |  Warn1
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 05 | test |2016-01-03 10:00:00|  10   | 0   | 11   | Error       |  0
 05 | test |2016-01-03 09:00:00|  10   | 0   | 10   | Started     |  0
```

EDIT: Clarification: The sp should return only the rows of an ID if it has the maximum Status = @maxStatus

if for example @maxStatus = 30 and @description='Waiting' , the only id that has a maxium Status of 30 and a description of waiting is '03' ; all the others have the maximum Status different from @maxStatus

```
 Id | Name |   Date            |  Age  | Bin |Status| Description |  Warn1
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 03 | yttr |2016-01-02 12:30:00|  16   | 0   | 30   | Waiting     |  0
 03 | yttr |2016-01-02 10:00:00|  16   | 0   | 10   | No desc     |  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can as the below:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
    Tbl A
WHERE
    A.Id IN (SELECT B.Id FROM Tbl B WHERE B.Description  = @description) AND
    Status <= @maxStatus
```

**Updated**

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
    Tbl A
WHERE
    A.Id IN (SELECT B.Id FROM Tbl B WHERE B.Description  = @description) AND
    A.Id IN (SELECT C.Id FROM (SELECT B.Id, MAX(Status) MaxStatus FROM Tbl B GROUP BY B.Id) C WHERE C.MaxStatus <= @maxStatus )
```

Comment: It does the same thing as the above answer, and it ignores any other information for a particular id.

Comment: Show sample data please.

Comment: Sorry, there was an logic error on my part before storing the info in the #TempTable. It is correct, but not exactly what I was looking for, please see the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `exists`:

```
select t.*
from #tmp t
where exists (select 1
              from #tmp t2
              where t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.Status = @maxStatus and
                    t2.Description = @description
             );
```

If your table is large, then an index on `(id, status, description)` would help.

EDIT:

You seem to want the maximum of the statuses to match.  I'm not sure what `description` really has to do with the problem, because the description is the same for each status.  So, you could do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(status) over (partition by id) as maxstatus
      from #tmp t
     ) t
where maxStatus = @maxStatus
```

Comment: This does not work. It only returns the rows where maxStatus = Status and description = Description.  I need all the rows for the particular Id where the first row meets the conditions. For example 1 it returns only row 1 and 4

Comment: @DanielD. . . . This should return *all* rows for an `id` where any one of those rows contains the combination of the status and description that you want.

Comment: You are right, there was a little logic error in the procedure before i added the data into the #TempTable that was messing with the results. Please see the edited question for a clarification.

Comment: @DanielD. have you find your solution?

Comment: @Waqas Shabbir Yes, the accepted answer. I also wanted to filter by description, because there might be cases when the descriptions do not match. Thank you for your help, your solution works when filtering only by the Status

Comment: @DanielD. Have you tried my answer? It not only checks the status but also the description.

Comment: @WaqasShabbir Yes I tried it , but I got an error : "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: @DanielD. I have made a change in Querey. Replace 'IN' with '='. Now, Let me know about this one, that it solves your problem or not. So that I can check myself.

Comment: @WaqasShabbir Yes I tried replacing IN with = but I still got the same error.

Comment: @Daniel D. As per my knowledge, it is absolutely ok. Anyway you find your solution, its good

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT id, name, date, age, bin, status, description, warn1
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE id IN
          (
           SELECT id
           FROM TABLE_NAME
           WHERE  status=@maxStatus 
           AND description=@description
          )
```